# Creating a function in mysql

Tags: mysql

I would like to create a function or procedure that I can use in mysql but I'm not sure what the syntax would be. What I want to do is take the value from a column and see if it's a 1 or 2, and based on that, return the value from either column A or B.
So for example, my select function would be something like:

```
select a, b, c, functionA(c) from table;
```

Below is the pseudo-code of my function

```
functionA(int x){
      if(x==1)
          //return value in column A
      else
          //return value in column B
}
```

Comment: you can do this without using a function and it will perform better. select case when c=1 then a else b end from table

Comment: @Gordy - this should be posted as an answer below.

Comment: @oipsl: it is a time to remove `SQL` and `mysql` from `known` array in your profile ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a, b, c, IF(c=1, a, b) from table;
```

or you can use `select case` but I think `IF` is more readable.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

A function won't be able to return anything from the table that you don't pass in. To do what you want requires 3 parameters:

```
create function functionA(p1 integer, p2 integer, p3 integer) returns integer
begin
    if p1 = 1 then
        return p2
    else
        return p3
    end if;
end;
```

..and your query would be:

```
select a, b, c, functionA(c, a, b) from table;
```

However it's more efficient and easier to just case or if for such a simple query:

```
select case when c=1 then a else b end from table;
```